# javascript if elseif else not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Help! The if/elseif/else code block won't work! When the code reaches prompt "what will you do?" no matter what you type, you get all the alerts. It should come up blank when you type a command that is not in the if blocks, and give you an alert if you did type R, L or M. Typing F should give you no alert.

```
while (Room = 1) {
    var Choice = prompt ("What will you do?");
    if (Turn = "Start");
    {
        if (Choice = "F");
    {
        Turn = "1";
    }
    else if (Choice = "R");
    {
        alert ("You cannot do that...");
    }
    else if (Choice = "L");
    {
        alert ("You cannot do that...");
    }
    else if (Choice = "M");
    {
        alert ("    1"+'\n'+"    1" + '\n' + "221" + '\n' + "    X");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert ("You cannot do that...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code before you submit your question.

Comment: Remove `;` from the ends of your `if` and `elseif` lines..

Comment: You need to use == for comparison instead of =

Comment: Hamatti actually helped a lot...

Comment: Andy, you should spend less time criticising others and more time working on your website ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon after all your if-elseif-statements. So regardless of what the boolean is inside the if, the if block is empty. Just remove semicolons and you're good to go.

With this:

```
if(1 == 1);
{
    alert('Nope');
}
```

the block after if-statement is always executed because of the semicolon ending the if.

```
if(1 == 1)
{
   alert('Yup');
}
```

Works.

Comment: I accepted this answer but I am also considering using the "switch" command.

Answer (score 5):

Use `==` instead of `=`. A single equals is a variable assignment and evaluates to the result of the assignment. `==` is used for equality test.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` from your if and else if statement.

> `;` represents end of statement

Also you can't use `=` as comparison operation, instead `==` or `===`(strict comparison) as @Andy mentioned.

```
while (Room == 1) { // Actually your code fails at the beginning itself.
```

However I would suggest you to use **`switch`** for your case.

Comment: `switch(Choice) case "R":alert ("You cannot do that...");` you can extend this.  Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you write **"="** single equal to means assignment of value to that variable.
So, You should change the **"="** Single equalto to **"=="** Double equalto for conditional purpose.

And If else has no end **";"** Semi-Colon required in Javascript. removed it.

I have updated the following please try it.

```
while (Room == 1) {
    var Choice = prompt ("What will you do?");
    if (Turn == "Start")
    {
        if (Choice == "F")
        {
            Turn == "1";
        }
        else if (Choice == "R")
        {
            alert ("You cannot do that...");
        }
        else if (Choice == "L")
        {
            alert ("You cannot do that...");
        }
        else if (Choice == "M")
        {
            alert ("    1"+'\n'+"    1" + '\n' + "221" + '\n' + "    X");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert ("You cannot do that...");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolons `;` at the end of the `if` and `else if` loops

and also compare string by using `==`, not `=`

Replace your code with this one

```
while (Room = 1) { //here Room is int variable
  var Choice = prompt ("What will you do?");
  if (Turn == "Start")
  {
    if (Choice =="F")
    {
      Turn = "1";
    }
    else if (Choice == "R")
    {
      alert ("You cannot do that...");
    }
    else if (Choice == "L")
    {
      alert ("You cannot do that...");
    }
    else if (Choice == "M")
    {
      alert ("1" + '\n' + "1" + '\n' + "221" + '\n' + "X");
    }
    else 
    {
      alert ("You cannot do that...")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java scrip don't consider single '=' it works with '=='

```
try
if (Turn == "Start");

Instead of
if (Turn = "Start");
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, besides using strict comparison I would strongly suggest writing left curly brace just after if(...) not in the new line:

Like:

`if(...){`

Instead of:

```
if(...)
{
```

Reason for that is JavaScript's built-in semi-colon insertion, so sometimes it can produce silent errors or unexpected behavior. In some other programming languages it doesn't matter, but in JavaScript it does.